# Launch Connectivity screen of OS from Wear application

Tags: settings, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

Is there any way in wear app, to redirect a user to a "Connectivity" screen which is added below,

[image]

**Notes:**   able to open only Bluetooth or Wi-Fi or Airplane mode using  the setting intent given in this link
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved using  **Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS** intent